# How to have a loop going continuously and be able to use cin?

Tags: c++, loops, cin

Okay so i have been trying to make a program that has a loop adding to a value by one and being able to do std::cin but once i get to the std::cin it pauses my loop. it there anyway to be able to do std::cin and keep my loop going?

Here is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int a = 1;
int answer;
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        a = a + 1;
        Sleep(100);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1))
        {
            cout << "Would you like to print the value of a?" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer = 'yes')
            {
                cout << a << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside that, `answer = 'yes'` has two weird points: assignment as condition expression and implementation-defined multi-character character literal.

Comment: Your sample does not even compile, it is missing includes.  Also please compile with a higher warning level and fix the warnings. They point you to the errors in your code.

Comment: yes i see it wont compile the iostream didn't copy and i wrote this at 5am just as a example.

Answer (score 0):

std::cin is a blocking method, which makes the process stop and wait for an input without running any other code. You could consider starting the blocking std::cin call on a separate thread. You would need some way of communicating between the two threads so that you can print out the value a in the blocking thread and increment it in the other one.
So you would need to make the variable a thread safe like with a monitor.

Hope it helps :D I am new here^^